# How to order MySQL records by Unix timestamps in descending order?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I order records in a PHP query to MySQL by a field that contains `TIME()` timestamps in descending order?

Comment: sort order ascending or descending?

Comment: -1 for unclear.  Query result or array?

Comment: In a query result, ordering descending

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `ORDER BY` clause like this:

```
SELECT …
FROM …
ORDER BY timestamp_field DESC
```